# Discover new files

Tags: php, apache, filesystems

I have a network storage device that contains a few hundred thousand mp3 files, organized by `[artist]/[album]` hierarchy. I need to identify newly added artist folders and/or newly added album folders programmatically on demand (not monitoring, but by request).

Our dev server is Windows-based, the production server will be FreeBSD. A cross-platform solution is optimal because the production server may not always be *nix, and I'd like to spend as little time on reconciling the (unavoidable) differences between the dev and production server as possible.

I have a working proof-of-concept that is Windows platform-dependent: using a `Scripting.FileSystemObject` COM object I am iterating through all top-level (artist) directories and checking the size of the directory.  If there is a change, then the directory is further explored to find new album folders. As the directories are iterated, the path and file size is collected into an array, which I write serialized into a file for next time.  This array is used on a subsequent call, both to identify changed artist directories (new album added) as well as identifying completely new artist directories.

This feels convoluted, and as I mentioned it is platform-dependent. **To boil it down, my goals are:**

- **Identify new top-tier directories**
- **Identify new second-tier directories**
- **Identify new loose files within the top-tier directories**

Execution time is not a concern here, and security is not an obstacle: this is an internal-only project using only intranet assets, so we can do whatever has to be done to facilitate the desired end result.

Here's my working proof-of-concept:

```
    // read the cached list of artist folders
    $folder_list_cache_file = 'seartistfolderlist.pctf';
    $fh = fopen($folder_list_cache_file, 'r');
    $folder_list_cache = fread($fh, filesize($folder_list_cache_file));
    fclose($fh);

    if (!$folder_list_cache)
        $folder_list_cache = '';

    $folder_list_cache = unserialize($folder_list_cache);
    if (!is_array($folder_list_cache))
        $folder_list_cache = array();

    // container arrays
    $found_artist_folders = array();
    $newly_found_artist_folders = array();
    $changed_artist_folders = array();

    $filesystem = new COM('Scripting.FileSystemObject');

    $dir = "//network_path_to_folders/";
    if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
        // loop the directories
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            // skip non-entities
            if ($file == '.' || $file == '..')
                continue;

            // make a key-friendly version of the artist name, skip invalids
            // ie 10000-maniacs
            $file_t = trim(post_slug($file));
            if (strlen($file_t) < 1)
                continue;

            // build the full path
            $pth = $dir.$file;

            // skip loose top-level files
            if (!is_dir($pth))
                continue;

            // attempt to get the size of the directory
            $size = 'ERR';
            try {
                $f = $filesystem->getfolder($pth);
                $size = $f->Size();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                /* failed to get size */
            }

            // if the artist is not known, they are newly added
            if (!array_key_exists($file_t, $folder_list_cache)) {
                $newly_found_artist_folders[$file_t] = $file;
            } elseif (array_key_exists($file_t, $folder_list_cache) && $size != $folder_list_cache[$file_t]['size']) {
                // if the artist is known but the size is different, a new album is added
                $changed_artist_folders[] = $file;
            }

            // build a list of everything, along with file size to write into the cache file
            $found_artist_folders[$file_t] = array (
                'path'=>$file,
                'size'=>$size
            );
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }

// write the list to a file for next time
    $fh = fopen($folder_list_cache_file, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, serialize($found_artist_folders));
    fclose($fh);

     // deal with discovered additions and changes....
```

Another thing to mention: because these are MP3s, the sizes I'm dealing with are big. So big, in fact, that I have to watch out for PHP's limitation on unsized integers. The drive is currently at 90% utilization of 1.7TB (yes, SATA in RAID), a new set of multi-TB drives will be added soon only to be filled up in short order.

**EDIT**

I did not mention the database because I thought it would be a needless detail, but there IS a database. This script is seeking new additions to the digital portion of our music library; at the end of the code where it says "deal with discovered additions and changes", it is reading ID3 tags and doing Amazon lookups, then adding the new stuff to a database table. Someone will come along and review the new additions and screen the data, then it will be added it to the "official" database of albums available for play. Many of the songs we're dealing with are by local artists, so the ID3 and Amazon lookups don't give the track titles, album name, etc. In that case, the human intervention is critical to fill in the missing data.

Comment: For a similar task with a similar sized library, we just keep everything in a MySQL database.  A PHP script blows right on through this no problem!

Comment: There is indeed a database... this code is to auto-detect new additions, as well as to identify any disconnects between what the database expects is there and what is actually there.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams - the files themselves are not >2GB, the folders are. These are highest-quality audio files for airplay on a radio station.

Comment: Radio stations don't like FLAC?

Comment: I do - but it wasn't up to me. There are unpaid volunteers doing the CD ripping, and they're all over the place.  It was all I could do to get them to use **some** consistent format and naming convention. They're using Windows Media Player to rip :( Never before has "choose your battles" had so much meaning to me. Imagine a room with 20,000 CDs on shelves, and a guy walks in and says "Turn these all to MP3s." Ayyyyeeeee!

Comment: Given that even HD radio maxes out around 300kb/s bitrate, 320kb/s MP3 seems just fine. FLAC is for those listening to symphony in a holocaust bunker with $10,000 headphones. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest thing for the BSD-side is a `find` script that simply looks for inodes with a ctime greater than the last time it ran.

Leave a sentinel file somewhere to 'store' the last run time, which you can do with a simple

```
touch /tmp/find_sentinel
```

and then

```
find /top/of/mp3/tree --cnewer /tmp/find_sentinel
```

which will produce a list of files/directory which have been changed since the find_sentinel file was touched. Running this via cron will get you regular updates, and the script doing the find can them digest the returned file data into your database for processing.

You could accomplish something similar on the Windows-side with [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com), which'd provide an identical 'find' app.

Comment: Liking this, though I want to mess with Ignacio's suggestion too, since it would be less platform-specific. Although, it looks like `DirectoryIterator` is little more than a replacement for the COM object I'm using, meaning my method doesn't really change. Thanks!

Comment: I accepted this answer because the concept is what I ended up using, if not the specific method. I re-wrote my directory loops to use the DirectoryIterator class as @Ignacio suggested, but rather than checking the size as I was doing in my PoC, I am using the `getMTime` method to grab the last-modified timestamp and using it to determine changes in the directories. This also seems to be less processor-intensive than checking the size, though I have not benchmarked that observation. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Chris: size and timestmap data all comes out of a stat() call on the file. All that data's retrieved in one fell swoop, so it doesn't matter what you're retrieving in the way of metadata, it's still just one stat() call per file (and the results are cached as well).

Comment: Ah, then it was the caching that caused the marked improvement in speed.  As I said, I hadn't performed a benchmark by any stretch, I wasn't even sure if the speed increase was perceptual only - I was so happy that I got a working solution that I thought, "Hey, it is faster too!" :)

Answer (score 1):

[`DirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) will help you walk the filesystem. You should consider putting the information in a database though.

Comment: I'll look in to this further, this would pretty much serve as a replacement for the COM object but I still have to do the looping and dancing that I'm already doing, correct?

Comment: Can't really get around the looping if you're doing it in a programming language.

Comment: `$awesome = $iterator->superConvenient()->listAllTheNewFiles();`

Comment: I accepted the other answer because it was closer conceptually to my final code, but I appreciate your input here - I am using the `DirectoryIterator` rather than the older `opendir` method I was employing. A few things I was a little disappointed to find while working with this class: there are several methods that are not implemented in my very-typical build of PHP, such as `getExtension`; and the class cannot pull the size of a directory using the `getSize` method - it returns 0 if the subject is not a file. This still beats the heck out of the old filesystem functions!

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with a solution that enumerates the contents of each folder in a MySQL database; your scan can quickly check against the contents listed in the database, and add entries that aren't already there.  This gives you nice enumeration and searchability of the contents, and should be plenty fast for your needs.